# Write to /etc/hosts in docker container when running docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to write to the file in `/etc/hosts` within a `docker` container when I perform the run command, but when I shh into the container and check the `hosts` file, nothing has been written.

What is the correct command to do this?

I am running my image with the following command:

`docker run -it -p 3000:3000 <imageName> bash echo 192.168.56.101 mypath.dev >> /etc/hosts`

Comment: `-it` and `-d` are conflicting. The first spawns an interactive terminal, the second lets it run as a daemon in the background. Please fix that first.

Comment: ahh, sorry. I had been playing around with it and forgot to remove the `-d`

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the first semicolon. I'd start a bash with `docker run ... myimage bash` (no semicolon here).

Comment: My problem is not with starting a bash. It's adding the IP address to the hosts file so that I don't have to do it manually everytime.

Comment: The IP address that you want to include in /etc/hosts is for another container in your docker host? This is not the best ways to connect containers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ["add-host" parameter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etc-hosts) when running the container:

```
docker run -it --add-host db-static:86.75.30.9 ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
```